# How can display home page web app A from web app B with ajax and request header "Bearer token"

Tags: javascript, java, html, ajax

I want to connect from web app A with address "http://172.20.30.15:8180" to web app B with address "http://172.20.40.15:8080" that have security OAuth2 and my browser is Firefox. I use ajax for connecting with head "Bearer token". Pls help me how can display home web app B From web app A?

When I use pushstate I catch error, "

ecurityError: The operation is insecure"

My code in web app A is like :

// ajax

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://172.20.40.15:8080/B', 
    headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
    method: 'POST',
    data: YourData,
    success: function(data){

```
  history.pushState({}, '','http://172.20.40.15:8080');
  window. Writ(data) ;
```

});

Comment: What is _"app"_? An HTML `document`?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: please post your ajax code.